# ASP.NET Boilerplate V7.x not working with compiled models for EF Core 6.x

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-6.0

EF Core 6 provides a feature called "Compiled Models" for better query performance (10x faster) but ABP V7.x cannot run compiled models. It throw the following exception:

> Entity 'Edition' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'EditionFeatureSetting'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Edition' has a query filter configured. Compiled model can't be generated, because query filters are not supported.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.Create(IEntityType entityType, CSharpRuntimeAnnotationCodeGeneratorParameters parameters)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.CreateEntityType(IEntityType entityType, IndentedStringBuilder mainBuilder, IndentedStringBuilder methodBuilder, SortedSet`1 namespaces, String className, Boolean nullable)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.GenerateEntityType(IEntityType entityType, String namespace, String className, Boolean nullable)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpRuntimeModelCodeGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, CompiledModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CompiledModelScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(IModel model, String outputDir, CompiledModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.Optimize(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, String contextTypeName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OptimizeContextImpl(String outputDir, String modelNamespace, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OptimizeContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> The entity type 'Edition' has a query filter configured. Compiled model can't be generated, because query filters are not supported.

Please help and support this problem, because compiled models is very very important for query performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not caused by ABP.  Your EF context has at least one query filter configured.  Compiled models do not support any query filters at this time, although it is on the backlog for a future release (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24897)).

The only options for the moment are to forego query filtering or forego compiled models.

Comment: This is the original Context from ASP.Net Boilerplate, you can try down load and run database migration. you will see the problem. here is the link: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates

Comment: You will have to remove the tenant ID query filters from the Entity Framework context (take a look at OnModelCreating) before you can use their template with compiled models. Be aware - this will break the multitenancy features of their template. I'd recommend not using compiled models with their template until EF supports query filters in compiled models.

Comment: There is no code in DbContext


namespace AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class AbpProjectNameDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, AbpProjectNameDbContext>
    {
        /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */
        
        public AbpProjectNameDbContext(DbContextOptions<AbpProjectNameDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

We are add `globle` filter. In Function `CreateAnnotations` of file `EntityType`

```
public static void CreateAnnotations(RuntimeEntityType runtimeEntityType)
{
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:FunctionName", null);
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:Schema", null);
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:SqlQuery", null);
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:TableName", "Application");
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:ViewName", null);
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation("Relational:ViewSchema", null);
    Expression<Func<Application, bool>> expression = Application => !Application.IsDeleted;
    runtimeEntityType.AddAnnotation(CoreAnnotationNames.QueryFilter, expression);
    Customize(runtimeEntityType);
}
```